# Grails MongoDB ${it} first three entrys of array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, grails, each

after a day of trial and error, maybe someone can give me a hint for solving my problem?

My task is to develope the Frontend of a Grails-Application with MongoDB
and i want to express that only the first three entrys of a JSON-array will be in a div as listpoints and the next three entrys in another div as li´s.

in the following examples he just adds each entry in li`s :

```
<g:each in="${profil.leistung}">
 <div>
 <li> ${it} </li>
</div>
</g:each>
```

I tried several stuff, but did not get it
Hope For Help, will make a lot of Backflips on my laptop for solving!
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about JSON arrays specifically, but with normal arrays or Lists you could do this with careful use of slicing:

```
<g:each var="chunk" in="${0..<(profil.leistung.size().intdiv(3) +
                               (profil.leistung.size() % 3 ? 1 : 0))}">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <g:each in="${profil.leistung[(chunk * 3)..<(Math.min(
                                  profil.leistung.size(), (chunk + 1) * 3))]}">
        <li>${it}</li>
      </g:each>
    </ul>
  </div>
</g:each>
```

What I'm doing here is working out how many chunks of three elements we could break the list into (the last chunk may have fewer than three elements), then each time through the outer loop slice out elements `3n` inclusive to `3(n+1)` exclusive or the end of the list (whichever comes first).  If you know that your list length will *always* be an exact multiple of three then you can remove the edge cases:

```
<g:each var="chunk" in="${0..<profil.leistung.size().intdiv(3)}">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <g:each in="${profil.leistung[(chunk * 3)..<((chunk + 1) * 3)]}">
        <li>${it}</li>
      </g:each>
    </ul>
  </div>
</g:each>
```

Comment: wow, it works perfectly, several backflips were performed.Lot´s of thank you,youre a genious

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  A bit of friendly advice though - forget the backflips.  The way to gain respect on SO is to ask good questions, making sure you include all the relevant information and no noise, and accept good answers.

Comment: Thanks, got it. Respect to all people like you giving very good answers, this was my second question and i´m really flattered by this platform!!!